# Angular2 + jquery autocomplete Component: unable to call methods on component inside spec file

Tags: jquery-ui, angular, jquery-autocomplete, angular2-testing

I have jquery autocomplete method being used inside angular2 which calls service to fetch data from api.
Here is **myComponent.ts** :

```
export class myComponent {
private myVar;
private binding1;
private binding2;
constructor( @Inject(ElementRef) private elementRef: ElementRef,private _myService: MyService) {

}
public method1() { return this.myVar.val().toUpperCase(); }
public method2() { return this.myVar.val(""); }

private ngOnInit() {
    var _this = this;
    this.myVar = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).children().eq(0).autocomplete({
        source: function(request,callback){
            _this.mainMethod(request,callback);
        },
delay:0,
select: (event, ui) => {
// …},
open: function(e,ui)
{
    //…
},
appendTo: $('body')
});

//renderMethod add data to the view using $().append()

public mainMethod (res, callback) { //gets called from inside autocomplete
if(condition 1) {
//renders data from service by calling methodOnService()
//returns binding1 and binding2  which gets rendered in view (see html)
}
else {
//call anotherMethod();
//sets binding1 and binding2  which gets rendered in view (see html)

}
}
public anotherMethod() {
//…
}
```

**myComponent.html**:

```
<input type="text" value="{{binding1}}" size="{{binding2}}" maxlength="94"><span></span>
```

I’m finding it hard to test the code since it is mixing angular with jquery (which is not good I know). But right now, I want to call method1, method2, mainMethod, anotherMethod from my test file to get more code coverage.

**myComponent.spec.ts** file :

```
fit(‘my component test file’,inject([TestComponentBuilder, MyComponent, ElementRef], (tcb:TestComponentBuilder) => {
        tcb.createAsync(MyComponent)
            .then((fixture) => {

                const element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
                const instance = fixture.componentInstance;
                console.log("component instance", fixture.componentInstance);
                fixture.componentInstance.binding2 =12;
                fixture.componentInstance.binding1 = 'aapl';

                spyOn(instance, "methodOnService");
                spyOn(instance,"anotherMethod");
                fixture.detectChanges(); //while debugging, it invokes 'ngOnInit' method but doesn't invoke autocomplete method
                fixture.componentInstance.symbol= 'aa';
                fixture.componentInstance.binding2 =12;
                fixture.detectChanges(); //it doesn't even invoke 'ngOnInit'


                 expect(instance.methodOnService.calls.any()).toEqual(true); //error : Expected false to equal true
                expect(instance.anotherMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
// error :Expected spy anotherMethod to have been called.
```

Even For calling method1 and method2, I'm unable to mock this.myVar in spec ? how should i go about testing various method ?

Comment: What do you mean by mock `this.myVar` what do you try to accomplish?

Comment: `this.myVar` stores jQuery Object and on calling `method1` in spec file it says can't find `.val()` of undefined. so `this.myVar` is not getting mocked

Comment: Mocked by what? Why do you expect it to get mocked?

Comment: I just want to invoke`method1` in spec file. By mocking i meant it contains jQuery object returned in `ngOnInit`. I updated my spec file. Did you get the problem now?

Comment: I don't see you doing anything that would cause `myVar`, or `method1` to be mocked. I don't get it :-/

Comment: your are right. Leave method1 as of now. Can you pin point why i'm unable to call autocomplete method on second change detection. (read my comments in spec file)

Comment: `ngOnInit()` isn't supposed to be invoked by each `fixture.detectChanges()`. `fixture.detectChanges()` is just to manually invoke Angulars change detection that normally runs automatic (on ever event or async call). `ngOnInit()` is only invoked once after the first change detection. You would need to destroy and recreate the test component to `ngOnInit()` being called again.

Comment: Thanks!!  I will try that. Can you pass on some useful link that might be helpful?

Comment: Useful link for testing? Just angular.io I don't know if they published something already about testing. The last time I checked it was not very much, but they are constantly working on docs.

Comment: if I've created a component instance using TestComponentBuilder.createAsync() , then how to delete that and create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Not actually an answer (don't really understand the problem) but some suggestions (see comments in code):

```ts
export class myComponent {
  private myVar;
  private binding1;
  private binding2;

  // remove `@Inject(ElementRef)` because it's redundant whent the type is
  // also `ElementRef`
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,private _myService: MyService) {
  }

  public method1() { return this. myVar.val().toUpperCase(); }
  public method2() { return this. myVar.val(""); }

  private ngOnInit() {
    //var _this = this;
    this.myVar = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).children().eq(0).autocomplete({
        source: (request,callback) => { // <<=== use arrow instead of `function`
            this.mainMethod(request,callback);
        },
    delay:0,
    select: (event, ui) => {
    // …},
    open: (e,ui) => { // <<=== use arrow instead of function
      //…
    },
    appendTo: $('body')
  });

  //renderMethod add data to the view using $().append()

  public mainMethod(res, callback) { //gets called from inside autocomplete
    if(condition 1) {
      //renders data from service by calling methodOnService()
      //returns binding1 and binding2  which gets rendered in view (see html)
    } else {
      //call anotherMethod();
      //sets binding1 and binding2  which gets rendered in view (see html)
    }
  }

  public anotherMethod() {
  //…
  }
}
```